# Android : Google map is not updating while zooming in

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Map API V2 in my app development. There is no any problem to displaying map at init condition with default zoom in. But when I try to zoom in map then it is not updating as I want. When I zoom in more then it's just blank map and not loading anything there. I was waiting to load, but there is no response.
Thanks.

**Java**

```
// Google Map Initialization

        try { 
            if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Google Map Initialization ends


        // Google Map Manipulation


        MapTypeChange.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(googleMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN) {
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                    MapTypeChange.setText("Terrain");
                }
                else {
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                    MapTypeChange.setText("Satellite");
                }
            }
        });


        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Gaurav"))
        .showInfoWindow();

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(50, 50))
        .title("Rohit")).showInfoWindow();

        Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
         .add(new LatLng(10, 10), new LatLng(50, 50))
         .width(5)
         .color(Color.RED)
         .geodesic(true));

        // Google Map Manipulation Ends
```

**XML**

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" >
        </fragment>
```

**Manifest Permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.beproject.ourway.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Comment: Map you are able to see, might be cached one. Do uninstall - install and try again.

Comment: I have tried that also. But there is no change :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map you see is the cached one. You are probably using and expired/invalid API key for the [Google Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). Once you change it to a working one, the issue should be solved.

The keys are obtained from the Google Developer Console which I recon you are familiar with since you've come this far.